# Ayuda con mi conversor a csv

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

Estoy haciendo un conversor de `xsl` y `xlsx` a `csv` pero estoy teniendo problemas con las fechas. Cuando me viene una fecha en una de las celdas, no se me queda en `dd/mm/yyyy`, si no que se cambia a `mm/dd/yyy`, ¿alguna solución?

Estoy utilizando la librería de `APACHE POI` y Java 7

```
//Esto es simplemente una clase que se utiliza para transformar xls y xlsx a csv
public class Conversor_a_csv {

public static void echoAsCSV(Sheet sheet, Objeto_Ditto objeto) throws IOException {

    objeto.setMicrodatos(objeto.getExcel() + ".csv");
    File csv = new File(objeto.getMicrodatos());
    BufferedWriter bw;
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

    String v_Fila = "";

    //https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html
    Row row = null;
    Cell cell = null;
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.FRENCH);
    DateFormat formatterDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date v_Fecha;
    for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        v_Fila = "";
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (row != null) {
            for (int x = 0; x < row.getLastCellNum(); x++) {
                cell = row.getCell(x);
                //Comprovamos que la celda es tipo fecha
                if(cell != null && cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC && DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                    //Aqui tocaria tratrar la celda para que nos la copie de forma correcta
                    v_Fecha = cell.getDateCellValue();
                    v_Fila = v_Fila + formatterDate.format(v_Fecha) + ";";
                }else{
                    v_Fila = v_Fila + formatter.formatCellValue(cell).trim() + ";";
                }
            }
            bw.write(v_Fila);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
    bw.close();
}

/**
 * @param objeto
 * @throws org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
 */
public static void conversor(Objeto_Ditto objeto) throws org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException {
    InputStream inp = null;
    try {
        inp = new FileInputStream(objeto.getExcel());
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        echoAsCSV(wb.getSheetAt(0), objeto);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            inp.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ya esta solucionado en el codigo de arriba. Gradcias.

Comment: ¿En qué formato está en el xls original?

Comment: @PabloLozano si te refieres a la celda con la fecha, me la estan enviando sin formato, de momento he descubierto que si ponen "-" y no "/" lo trata como string y la copia bien, pero eso no es una solucion ya que el xls que me pasan esta predefinido y no puedo decir que me lo pasen de esa forma.

Comment: No edites tu pregunta con la solución, deja la pregunta con el problema y pon tu solución como respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

En estas lineas:

```
//String excelFormatPattern = DateFormatConverter.convert(Locale.FRENCH, "dd MMMM, yyyy");
//DateFormat dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, new Locale("es_ES"));
```

Veo que te falta una coma en el primer comentario. No sé si eso soluciona nada. Otra cosa que te iba a comentar es que en vez de DateFormat puedes usar

```
 new SimpleDateFormat(dd-MM-yyy);
```

No lo he probado es algo que encontré en Internet. Este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy) a lo mejor ayuda. Si usases Java 8 sería mucho más fácil, creo yo.

Comment: Esto es un comentario y debería ir en la seccion de comentarios, no en la de soluciones :)